# How to implement File Transfer in jabber net

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp

Currently I created the chating application which is windows application(c#).
I created basic Client version which help of jabber net which internally uses XMPP protocol and openfire server.Now I had to implement File Transfer between two users in jabber net.
I have searched lot but there no solution for this aproach in c#

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014595/how-to-implement-socks5-file-transfer-xep-0065-in-jabber-net-library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk.html supports Filetransfers. It's released under a dual license for commecial and open source use. You can also compile a C++ libary and use the function in your C# code. [Gloox](http://camaya.net/gloox/) is a well known libary, that support file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html

If your libraries don't have an implementation already, that might be rather complex.